# C++ How to declare and initialize a vector inside a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, member

I would like to print out the vector "colors" using the member function "print".

```
/* Inside .h file */
class Color
{
public:
    void print();

private:
    std::vector<std::string> colors; = {"red", "green", "blue"};
};

/* Inside .cpp file */

void Color::print() 
{ 
    cout << colors << endl;
}
```

But I get an error message saying:

```
Implicit instantiation of undefined template.
```

at the declaration and initialization of vector "colors" inside class body

And a warning:

```
In class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension.
```

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>`? Also, you'll need to get rid of the semicolon between `colors` and the `=` in your header file.

Comment: And a c++11 capable compiler.

Comment: Simply enable C++14 or C++11 in your compiler's flags. However, you'll still have trouble with `std::cout << colors` as there is no overload of `<<` for `std::vector`.

Comment: Apart from what hlt said, you are using cout to print a vector of strings, but cout doesn't know how to do it. What must be done (cycling over all the values of the vector and printing each one) might be obvious to you, but the compiler doesn't know it. Add an explicit for loop in your `Color::print()` function! And for example, should they be separated by a space, a comma, a comma and a space, a new-line character? You must decide it, there's no standard way! So hte way to do it is not even *that* obvious...

Comment: Please go to the trouble of making a [mcve].  It shouldn't be difficult.  You are probably missing the declaration of std::vector or std::string - and you *really* need to get rid of that semi-colon before the equals.

Comment: Also, tell us *exactly which line* is causing the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had lot of issues:

1. Writing once `std::` and then leave it.
2. Syntax error: `std::vector<std::string> colors; = {"red", "green", "blue"};`

   ```
                                               ^
   ```
3. You must iterate through the vector in order to get all items.

This is the code which works and displays what you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* Inside .h file */
class Color
{
public:
    void print();

private:
    std::vector<std::string> colors = {"red", "green", "blue"};
};

/* Inside .cpp file */

void Color::print() 
{ 
    for ( const auto & item : colors )
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Color myColor;

    myColor.print();
}
```

[Live](http://rextester.com/USX73671) example